# php server webservice doesn't return value

Tags: php, soap

i'm writing my first php webservice (server side) but the client call does not receive any data.
I'm checking the service with the SoapClient on the web (http://soapclient.com/SoapClient) recalling the AggiornaCampionati function and this is the reply:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 - <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.aicsparma.it/websrvs">
 - <SOAP-ENV:Body>  
 <ns1:AggCampiosResponse />   
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>  
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

that is empty (the return message is ok(AggCampiosResponse) )!
The server code is very simply:

```
<?php

function AggiornaCampionati($args) {
    //return gettype($args)." - ".print_r($args);
    return("Pippo");
}

function AggiornaCampionato($args) {
    //$args = (int)$args;
    return 10;
}

function AggiornaRisultati($args) {
    $args = (int)$args;
    return $args;
}

function AggiornaCategoria($args) {
    //$args = (int)$args;
    return 10;
}

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache

$server = new SoapServer("aicscalcio.wsdl");
$server->addFunction("AggiornaCampionati");
$server->addFunction("AggiornaCampionato");
$server->addFunction("AggiornaRisultati");
$server->addFunction("AggiornaCategoria");

try {
    $server->handle();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $server->fault('Sender', $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Why the string value is not returned?
Also the other functions do not return any value!!
How can i be sure the PHP function is recalled?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I cannot return directly the string!
The correct function is:

```
function AggiornaCampionati($args) {
return array( "sresult" => $args->nomeCampio,
    "iresult" => $args->id );
}
```

(in the meantime i also added an integer).
The same of other functions.